# HD Radeon 6950 cannot run multiple monitors

Tags: windows-7

I'm having troubles getting multiple monitors to run on my graphics card. I plug one via the hdmi, and one into the DVI (I have tried both available DVI ports). with one DVI port it does not even register the monitor, with the second one I go into the Catalyst Control Center and it gives me the option to swap between the HDMI and the DVI port. I guess since this is the flex edition I could just go get 2 DSP to HDMI converters, plug 2 monitors in through the available DSP, and than the 3rd one into the HDMI, but do you have any idea why it will not let me run one HDMI and one DVI?

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you are running the latest [ATI Drivers](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx) for your card
- Make sure your monitors are on the correct display setting (HDMI is on HDMI display, and DVI is on DVI display)
- What does Control Panel > Display > Change display settings > Detect do? Only show one monitor?

I have run into problems with multiple monitors on ATI cards far too often...